# pivot table with multiple columns in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

Here's my scenario:

I have a Event model and a Stage model, a event can have multiple stages and a stage could be assigned to multiple events. So Many-to-many. The thing is, a stage has a sort_order, and that sort_order could be different in each event. That's why I added the sort_order into the pivot table instead in, for example, the stage table.

table: events_stages

```
| event_id | stage_id | sort_order |
------------------------------------
|    1     |     1    |      1     |
|    1     |     2    |      2     |
|    1     |     5    |      3     |
```

The thing is when I'm going to relate the Stage with the events its in,
I'm doing something like in the StageController:

sending a post with `events: [1,2,3]` and `sort_order: [1,1,2]`

```
    $relatedEvents = array();

    foreach ($request->events as $key => $event)
    {
        $relatedEvents[] = array(
            'event_id' => $relatedEventId,
            'sort_order' => $request->sort_order[$key]
        );
    }

    $stage->events()->sync(
        $relatedEvents
    );
```

but rely simply in the order of the post, doesn't seem like a really good idea.

Does anyone have a nicer solution?

Thanks!

Comment: IMHO if you need additional fields in the pivot table probabily you need an additional model, something like EventStage.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes is better to create another model (and use it as a pivot) rather than use pivot table itself. You have more control. I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve.